# Cucumber error when compiling HTML reports

Tags: java, jenkins, cucumber, jenkins-plugins, cucumber-jvm

I'm using Cucumber for the Java implementation and after running my test suite on **Jenkins** I'm getting a **Java heap space error**. I've tried to raise the memory for the process but still get the error. I've also tried to raise the memory for the surefire and failsafe maven plugins but still doesn't work as the problem is not taking place during test/integration phases.

It happens when **compiling and generating the JSON reports** but also sometimes when running the tests. Any clues about it?

The error trace is:

```
[CucumberReportPublisher] Compiling Cucumber Html Reports ...
[CucumberReportPublisher] copying all json files from slave: /apps/hudson/workspace/cbs-billing-web-nightly1/trunk/cbs-billing-web-qa-test/target/cucumberReport to master reports directory: /apps/hudson/jobs/cbs-billing-web-nightly1/builds/2014-05-15_02-01-24/cucumber-html-reports
[CucumberReportPublisher] Found the following number of json files: 1
[CucumberReportPublisher] 0. Found a json file: cucumber.json
[CucumberReportPublisher] Generating HTML reports
FATAL: Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2882)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:100)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:390)
at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:224)
at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:284)
at java.util.regex.Matcher.appendReplacement(Matcher.java:746)
at java.util.regex.Matcher.replaceAll(Matcher.java:813)
at java.lang.String.replaceAll(String.java:2189)
at net.masterthought.cucumber.util.Util.U2U(Util.java:107)
at net.masterthought.cucumber.ReportParser.parseJsonResults(ReportParser.java:30)
at net.masterthought.cucumber.ReportParser.(ReportParser.java:18)
at net.masterthought.cucumber.ReportBuilder.(ReportBuilder.java:65)
at net.masterthought.jenkins.CucumberReportPublisher.perform(CucumberReportPublisher.java:97)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:804)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:776)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1030)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:725)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1695)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:519)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:231)
```

Comment: To add more Java heap space, increase the value of the `-Xmx` Java parameter

Answer (score 0):

I have usually seen this happening when you embed your own text in cucumber HTML reports using the `Scenario` object. I used to embed whole JSON objects in my cucumber reports using `scenario.write(myObject.toString())`, this caused the Cucumber Jenkins plugin to crash with Java heap space error that you mention. After I limited such writes to the report, everything started working fine.

Comment: I barely use this method, just to trace the users I'm using during the execution. Anyway, from now on I'll take into account that this call can be problematic.

Comment: How big is your `cucumber.json` that is mentioned in your question? What is the size when you remove `scenario.write` just for sh@#$# and giggles :)

Comment: Also do you have the latest cucumber jenkins plugin?